# How to create a new plot in a figure right below the first one after click event?

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive, subplot

Given a matrix (list of lists)

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 6, 8],
     [9, 12, 15]]
```

and a list `x = [1, 2, 3]`.

Each row `j (0 <= j <= 2)` of `A` consists of *y*-values so that 3 straight lines in total can be created in combination with `x`.

Now I want to plot these straight lines in the same plot with a special feature. If the user clicks on the graphic, an event handler should receive the *x*-position and create another plot right below the first one. This plot should be 1D and only visualise the data of the column in `A` whose index is given by the *x*-position.

Example: A click on *x = 1* should plot `[1 4 9]`, *x = 2* should plot `[2 6 12]` and so on.

I have already tried to add a subplot using `figure1.add_subplot(211)` for the first plots and `figure1.add_subplot(212)` within the event handler and it also did not work.

```
A = [[1 2 3], [4 5 6], [7 8 9]]
x = [1 2 3]
figure1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, A[0])
plt.plot(x, A[1])
plt.plot(x, A[2])

def onclick(event):
    Y = [A[i][int(event.xdata)] for i in range(0, 3)]
    plt.plot(Y)

figure1.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Comment: Note that ① what you call a matrix and an array are indeed, respectively, a _list of lists_ and a _list_ ; ② Python indexes starting from 0, you should change to `j (0 <=  j <= 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following script that does what was asked for in the question:

1. the callback function is heavily commented
2. a key point is that the axis limits are not automatically updated, you can use `ax.relim(); ax.autoscale_view()` (aknowledgement, this comes from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220931/2749397) from [asmus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565489/asmus)) in the callback or fix suitable limits beforehand, as I have opted to do.

here it is the script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

def get_x(event):
    x = event.xdata
    # if you clic outside the graph, do nothing
    if x is None : return
    # from abscissa to column index
    i = int(round(x)-1)
    # update the line ordinates --- this is much faster than redrawing
    # the line, in this example it doesn't matter but possibly one
    # deals with larger data sets...
    line.set_ydata([row[i] for row in A])
    # we start with a clean subplot, if we haven't already placed a
    # line in it it's high time to do that
    if a2.lines == [] : a2.add_line(line)
    # eventually it's the moment of redrawing the whole figure
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# the data
A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
x = [ 1, 2, 3]

# THE key issue is to set properly and in advance all the axes,
# hence the share{x,y}
f, (a1, a2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='col', sharey='col')
a1.grid(1), a2.grid(1)

# the first subplot, nitpick: adjust the y limits
a1.plot(x, list(zip(*A)))
a1.set_ylim(0, 10)

# prepare a line to be plotted in the second subplot
line = Line2D([1,2,3], [0,0,0], color='black')

# bind our callback and show the figure
f.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', get_x)
plt.show()
```

[image: the non-interactive figure]