# Modify y data in a line

Tags: matplotlib

I have the following script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                  

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
# draw a horizontal line y=0
line, = ax.plot(x, [0 for _ in x]) 
def mod_ydata(ev): 
    X = ev.xdata 
    if X is not None: 
        n = round(X) 
        line.set_ydata([n for _ in x]) 
        fig.canvas.draw_idle() 
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', mod_ydata)                          
plt.show()
```

- **Expected Behavior** the original horizontal line *y = 0* is cleared in response to a mouse click and a new horizontal line, *y =* round*(x)*
  is drawn, where *x* is the abscissa of the mouse click.
- **Unexpected Behavior** the original horizontal line is cleared and no new horizontal line is drawn.

I  checked in an interactive IPython terminal, using `line.get_ydata()`, that the callback does update the ordinates.

I have to say that I've played with `plt.ion()`, repeating `plt.show()` in the callback, using `a1.draw()`, etc always to no avail.

I understand that I'm probably missing the obvious, but here I am...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, it's just drawing the line outside of the visible y-limits.

- either you enforce proper y-limits beforehand (e.g. using `ax.set_ylim(-1,5)` before `plt.show()`)
- or you add the following lines inside `mod_ydata()`, right before the call to `fig.canvas.draw_idle()`:

```py
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
```

although the latter makes the "movement" of the line kind of hard to see.